# How to install the proxy plugin behind a proxy for vagrant

Tags: ruby, windows, powershell, proxy, vagrant

I work on a restrictive proxied network and I currently have vagrant working on a laptop.  I had to use the proxy plugin and i had to install it off of my work network.

I am now on a desktop - where this is not possible (on windows) and I'm trying to configure vagrant.  The command I suspect I'm supposed to type is:

`vagrant plugin install --plugin-source http://rubygems.org vagrant-proxyconf`

Which is reporting:

```
Installing the 'vagrant-proxyconf' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

Could not fetch specs from http://gems.hashicorp.com/

Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source`
more than once without a block is a security risk, and may result in 
installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to 
indicate which gems should come from the secondary source. To upgrade
this warning to an error, run `bundle config disable_multisource true`.
```

I'm assuming this is related to a proxy issue.  I've tried both `cmd` and `PowerShell` as well as doing the

`set http_proxy=xxxxx:80`

Any suggestions?  I would be happy to do a manual install if thats possible somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this, if yes, can you please share here?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set proxy environment variables in the Vagrant host machine, so that it knows how to download the plugin.

For example:

```
$ export http_proxy=http://192.0.2.1:3128
$ export https_proxy=http://192.0.2.1:3128

$ env | grep http  # just checking
http_proxy=http://192.0.2.1:3128
https_proxy=http://192.0.2.1:3128

$ vagrant plugin install vagrant-proxyconf
Installing the 'vagrant-proxyconf' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-proxyconf (1.5.2)'!
```

Comment: How can I increase the timeout? Our Proxy is also scanning which can take longer than 60 sec (Default timeout)